VB.Net select a filename without opening the file
I am using VB.net and need a dialog box to be able to select a file name for exclusion.
The issue is that when you select a file to exclude such as pagefile.sys, after clicking ok, it gives you an error that the file is in use. Well obviously the file is in use, I'm just trying to  get the file name, not actually open the file. So how can I select a file name, but not open it? My code is below
    Using dialog As New OpenFileDialog
        dialog.Title = "Select a file to exclude from the backup"
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        If dialog.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Return
        MsgBox(dialog.FileName)
    End Using


For whatever odd reason, setting the "ValidateNames" property to False (before showing the dialog) will eliminate the "File Is In Use" prompt.  ie. in your case, dialog.ValidateNames = False

If your issue has been resolved then please either post an answer or delete the question. Leaving a question unanswered means that people will open it, read it and then read the comments, only to disco9ver that they've wasted their time.

I could be wrong but I suspect that the issue is the following. It looks like the FileDialog.FileExists method gets called and it does this: new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(fileName)).Assert();. My guess would be that that object cannot be created while the file is open. By not validating the file name, you avoid that check.

Setting the "ValidateNames" property to False eliminates this particular prompt about a file being "in use".
Using dialog As New OpenFileDialog
        dialog.Title = "Select a file to exclude from the backup"
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        dialog.ValidateNames = False   ' add this line to your existing code
        If dialog.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Return
        MsgBox(dialog.FileName)
    End Using

In theory, this is not exactly a perfect solution, because Microsoft's description of the "ValidateNames" property doesn't really mention anything about "in use" files.
So, use this solution with caution - if you really DO need the functionality that "ValidateNames = True" provides, you will obviously encounter the particular issue that was raised in this question.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.validatenames?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
